# Observable pattern applied in massive record update

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to apply **Observer** pattern to a class that contains a set of records.

In Java pseudo code my class is:

```
public class MyClass<E> extends Observable
{
    private ArrayList<E> items = new ArrayList<E>();

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public void add(E e)
    {
        this.items.add(e);

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void remove(E e)
    {
        if(this.items.remove(e))
        {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

My problem is: in some cases during program execution I have to do massive deletes and inserts of records in the structure and, for performances purposes, I would like that observer objects are notified only once at end of the whole operation.

Of course I can add some flag variables for handling the calls to `setChanged` and `notifyObservers`, but I wonder what is the "best" way to handle this kind of problem.

So my question: What is the best way to design the code to notify observer objects only once after a massive modification of the observed object?

Comment: in this case i think the best way is to create two methods deleteAll and addAll so you notify observers at the end of the operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have 2 general options

- let the client code explicitly disable notifications
- encapsulate a change in an own class and use a template method

Let's take a look at both options. I will use a simple `Observer` for my examples.

```
public class StdoutObserver implements Observer {
  @Override
  public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    System.out.println("Observable changed: " + o);
  }
}
```

**Client code explicitly disables notifications**

```
public class MyClass<E> extends Observable {
  private ArrayList<E> items = new ArrayList<E>();

  private boolean changing;

  public void setIsChanging(boolean changing){
    this.changing = changing;
    if(!changing && hasChanged()){
      notifyObservers();
    }
  }

  public void add(E e) {
    this.items.add(e);
    notifyChanged();
  }

  public void remove(E e) {
    if (this.items.remove(e)) {
      notifyChanged();
    }
  }

  private void notifyChanged(){
    setChanged();
    if(!changing){
      notifyObservers();
    }
  }
}
```

and the client code looks like this

```
MyClass<String> stringMyClass = new MyClass<String>();
stringMyClass.addObserver(new StdoutObserver());

System.out.println("setting changing: true");
stringMyClass.setIsChanging(true);

stringMyClass.add("C");
stringMyClass.add("D");
stringMyClass.add("E");

System.out.println("setting changing: false");
stringMyClass.setIsChanging(false);
```

Output will be

```
setting changing: true
setting changing: false
Observable changed: MyClass@229ed927
```

The problem with this solution is that the client code might forget to enable notifications (or tell the observable that the changes are done). In this case the notifications might be turned off forever.

**Encapsulate a change in an own class and use a template method**

Define an interface to represent the change

```
public interface ObservableChange<T extends Observable> {
    public void doChange(T observable); 
}
```

your `Observable` will then use a template method to ensure that the `changing` state is resetted when the change is done.

```
public class MyClass<E> extends Observable {

  private ArrayList<E> items = new ArrayList<E>();

  private boolean changing;

  public void update(ObservableChange<MyClass2<E>> observableChange) {
    setIsChanging(true);
    try {
      observableChange.doChange(this);
    } finally {
      setIsChanging(false);
    }

  }

  private void setIsChanging(boolean changing) {
    this.changing = changing;
    if (!changing && hasChanged()) {
      notifyObservers();
    }
  }

  public void add(E e) {
    this.items.add(e);
    notifyChanged();
  }

  public void remove(E e) {
    if (this.items.remove(e)) {
      notifyChanged();
    }
  }

  private void notifyChanged() {
    setChanged();
    if (!changing) {
      notifyObservers();
    }
  }
}
```

The client code will then look like this;

```
MyClass<String> stringMyClass = new MyClass<String>();
stringMyClass.addObserver(new StdoutObserver());


stringMyClass.update(new ObservableChange<MyClass<String>>() {
  @Override
  public void doChange(MyClass<String> observable) {
    observable.add("A");
    observable.add("B");
    observable.add("C");
    observable.add("D");
  }
});
```

and the output will be

```
Observable changed: MyClass2@33837697
```

Using a template method ensures that the notifications are only disabled as long as the changes are done, because the observer controls this.

Answer (score 0):

You see, if all your "big" operations use your own low-level add/remove functions, then you will constantly notify your observers.

This could be changed by providing **additional** methods, like in:

```
public void doSomeMassiveOperation(args) {
   do massive things directly on your list
   notify listeners
```

Another, much more hackish, wrong, not-to be used approach would be extending your interface this way:

```
public void disableNotifications() {
   this.notificationsEnabled = false;
}

public void enableNotificationsAndNotify() {
   this.notificationsEnabled = true;
   notify ...
}

public void add(E e) {
   add ...
   if (notificationsEnabled) {
     notify
}
```

Meaning: you allow users of your class to control "when" notifications happen. But that would basically mean that you move that responsibility to your client code.

Obviously option space is very limited here. So let me ask a counter question: do you only **assume** that mass operations and notifications will have severe performance impacts; or did you actually do some profiling (or is your setting like: "I many thousand list objects and many thousand observers that will do expensive things upon notifications")?

What I mean is: you have to balance a clear, good design with potential performance improvements. Meaning: only "give up" on good design when performance is **really proven** to be impacted.

Comment: The massive operations do have a severe impact: one of the observers must save the list on disk and then upload it on Google Drive.

Comment: Well, then maybe you should consider stepping back and re-design the whole thing. Maybe the whole observer idea isn't "strong" enough for your usecase. You know, there are architectures around message buses that are meant to be used for such kind high-load-throughput-high-everything scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. Can you provide me some links or examples of them please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add methods to MyClass:

```
public class MyClass<E> extends Observable {
    public void addAll(Collection<? extends E> e) {
        this.items.addAll(e);

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void removeAll(E e) {
        if(this.items.removeAll(e)) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }

    //UPDATE: 
    //you can define general purpose method

    public void modifyItems(Runnable modifier) {
        disableNotification();
        modifier.run();
        enableNotification();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    private void disableNotification() { ... }
    private void enableNotification() { ... }
}

...
myClass.modifyItems(
    () - {
        myClass.add(item);
        myClass.remove(item);
        ...
);
```

Two calls of method notifyObservers() can not cause any performance issuies.

Comment: Me too I thought at this solution, but my question was if this is the best way to handle this problem

Answer (score 0):

I like René Link answer. But his "Client code explicitly disables notifications" method has 2 disadvantages:

1) `stringMyClass.setIsChanging(false)` call can be avoided for some reason (exception, bad code etc)

2) If some other single items (out of bunch update) need to be added/deleted during massive bunch update - it also won't work

Romeo Sheshi commented simple and effective solution: use `deleteBulk()`, `addBulk()` methods with `notifyChanged()` method in it.